# Facebook php Oauth is not working

Tags: facebook-oauth

I'm new to facebook apps and php in general, and I have a bit of a problem. I cannot get OAuth to work correctly with my application. When you go the application itself, it does not redirect to the oAuth dialog. It merely displays a blank page that does nothing. If anyone can help me with this, I really need it haha. Thanks!
So far, my code is as follows:

```
<?php

   include_once ('santatree/facebook.php');


   $app_id = '276853929000834';
   $application_secret = 'e3a12b11221f3fef1e06952e15fdc8e4';

   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $app_id,
  'secret' => $application_secret,
  'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
));
?><?
if ($facebook->getSession())  
 {  
  $user = $facebook->getUser();  
 }  
else  
  {  
  $loginUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?    type=user_agent&display=page&client_id=276853929000834 
   &redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/digitalsanta/&scope=user_photos";  
  header("Location: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?        type=user_agent&display=page&client_id=276853929000834         &redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/digitalsanta/ &scope=user_photos");
  echo '';  
  }
```

Comment: you should mask your App ID & secret.

Comment: Is that odd spacing in the urls actually in your original code? And your redirect_uri value should definitely be urlencoded.

Comment: No, the spaces do not exist in the original code. Also, urlencode? As I stated previously, I am a beginner to PHP, and have no idea what to do with this. I searched for urlencode in the PHP manual but its description was ambiguous at best.

Comment: You need to construct the url like this: `$loginUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=276853929000834&scope=user_photos&redirect_uri=" . urlencode("http://apps.facebook.com/digitalsanta/");`

Answer (score 2):

I do my redirects based on the session token.

This assumes that you will be using the most recent php-sdk 3.1.1 and have Oauth2 enabled in your app settings.

SAMPLE HERE: login / out url is in footer of plugin.  http://apps.facebook.com/anotherfeed/TimeLineFeed.php?ref=facebook-stackoverflow

---

```
<?php
require './src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '',
  'secret' => '',
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
$access_token = $_SESSION['fb_135669679827333_access_token'];
if (!$access_token) {
echo '<script>';
echo 'top.location.href = "'.loginUrl.'";';
echo '</script>';
} else {
echo '<a href="'.logoutUrl.'">Logout</a>';
}
?>
```

---

https://developers.facebook.com/apps to edit your app.

- If you do not have an app you will need to create one.
- You will also need to set up the canvas and secure canvas urls to avoid errors.

[image]

Comment: Okay so I have essentially just copied and pasted your code with my own example; however, I am now returning an API 191 error that states my application does not own the domain, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: in your application settings you need to set the domain  see attached image and link edited in above.

Answer (score 1):

You only defined the variable `$loginUrl`, but you haven't redirect user to go to the URL. Consider using

`header("Location: $loginUrl");`

to forward your user if you haven't sent your header yet.

Comment: I have tried this route; however, doesn't the header function have to be sent before any other information, thus rendering an infinite loop?

Comment: Does anyone know how to redirect without header? I can't use header because then I can't validate whether or not the script has already been authorized before I redirect them

Comment: alternatively, you can use javascript / meta refresh technique to "transfer" your user to targeted page.

Comment: I don't understand your remarks about not being able to use header (it has nothing to do with being able to check authorization) but the normal way is to emit javascript which sets `top.location` to the oauth url. The reason is that using header will only redirect the iframe, and you need to redirect the entire page instead.